# Why does my car AC vents blow hot air when AC is switched off?

Tags: ac, climate-control

I bought a new car in the month of April 2019 but from the past few weeks, I have been experiencing very very hot air coming from all the vents.

The temperature is high to an extent wherein it becomes unbearable and I have to switch on AC (currently it's pleasant outside in my city so AC was not required).

I recently measured the temperature and it was greater than 44 degrees Celcius/108 degrees Farahenite. And I am sure I experienced hotter than this.

So bit worried and wanted to seek an opinion from the experts. Sharing some data:

AC unit type: Automatic Climatic Control

Route: Office to Home

Distance: 6 KM

AC status: Off

Re-circulation mode: Off

Windows: Rolled down

**Temperature: 43 degrees Celcius/108 degrees Fahrenheit**

Comment: Have you got the heater switched to hot?

Comment: Solar, I correctly remember, the temperature knob was at 21 degrees

Comment: If the a/c is off, as you state, then you can set 15 degrees but it won’t happen...

Comment: The automated door(s) that mix cold and warm (or hot) air (and also exclude one or the other, perhaps) is called the *blend door*. Some cars have one, some 2 or more. Some are mechanically actuated, some by electric motor or vacuum. Sound like it might be malfunctioning...

Comment: Jimmy, thank you for giving some insights. This may be a reason but I cannot have a look at it as the car is with the service center. 

The irony is that both the dealer and the manufacturer are considering this behavior as normal. Could you explain more about blend door?

Comment: What sort of climate do you live in? As Solar Mike said, if the AC is switched off then outside air will not be cooled so if it is 40 degrees ambient temperature outside then that is the coolest you will get blown through the vents, whatever the dial is set to, and is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The air from the engine is constantly blowing through your vents, the doors to close your vents from the engine must have broken and needs to be changed